# add unique constraint to existing table column

Tags: mysql

In mysql, when creating a table, you can append:

```
unique(username)
```

but i dont know how to alter a table to add that containt.

I was trying:

```
alter table Company constraint unique (username)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I mixed up the syntax.

```
alter table Company add constraint unique (username);
```

but this will fail if there are duplicates... So either drop and recreate if it is a sample db, or delete out duplicates.